# Inheritance keep or put into estate

Tags: life-insurance, inheritance

In the state of Alabama if you receive a life insurance payout does it have to go to the estate? I received a check separately from the estate but from the deceased estate.

Comment: Was the estate named as the beneficiary on the life insurance policy or were you named directly?

Comment: To the vote-to-closers - it would be kind to wait a bit, new members are put off by a quick close to their question.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your last sentence. Are you saying you received a check from the estate for your share of the estate and you also received a separate check from a life insurance company? If so, were you given a statement from the estate indicating what the check was for? And, presumably, it was not for the same life insurance policy you received a check for.

Comment: Your title mentions inheritance but your question appears to be about life insurance. Are you talking about both? Or just life insurance?